# Компиляция .java файлов программно

Tags: java, android

В корне sdcard на Android устройстве лежит `.java` файл, который нужно скопилировать в `.class` программно. Все бы ничего, если бы этот самый файлик не требовал подключение к библиотеки, написаной на Java 8. Возможно ли осуществить это? Какие идеи?

Мне нужно компилировать .java файлы именно программно, т.е. допустим юзер заходит в приложение на устройстве, указывает путь к своему .java файлу и оно компилируется там же.

Comment: А, что за библиотека?

Comment: вы можете, например, компилировать на сервере, и передавать запрос результат через интернет

Comment: Сомневаюсь что в андроид есть встроенный компилятор javac. А если не секрет, зачем компилировать программно?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android, это конечно не java но позволит загружать логику без компиляции.